# Tengo que setear esta variable de una clase que yo creé, pero solo lo hace temporalmente y cuando intento acceder a ella me manda null

Tags: java, poo, diseño-de-clases

Tengo esta clase que tiene una varible, de tipo Producto que yo la hice y tiene getProducto():

```
public class Celda {
    private Producto producto;
    private int stock;
    private String codigo;

    public Celda(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }
    public void ingresarProducto(Producto producto, int stock) {
        this.producto = producto;
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public Producto getProducto() {
        return producto;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
}
```

La clase producto existe y la hice yo, pero tengo otra clase con el siguiente método, que invoca el método que está en la clase Celda y se supone que ingresa el producto, por los test que hice si se añade el producto:

```
public void cargarProducto(Producto producto, String codigo,
                               int cantidadItems) {
        Celda celdaRecuperada = buscarCelda(codigo);
        celdaRecuperada.ingresarProducto(producto, cantidadItems);
    }
```

Pero el método cargarProducto no me setea bien los valores, y cuando intento acceder a un getProducto(), al no estar bien seteados me envia null, y cuando intento invocar el buscarCeldaProducto me da un null:

```
public class TestBuscarCeldaProducto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MaquinaDulces maquina=new MaquinaDulces();
        maquina.configurarMaquina("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2");
        
        Producto producto=new Producto("KE34","Papitas",0.85);
        maquina.cargarProducto(producto, "B1", 4);
        
        
        Celda celda=maquina.buscarCeldaProducto("KE34");
        System.out.println("Celda que contiene el producto:"+celda.getCodigo());
                
    }
}
```

El código del método anterior es:

```
public Celda buscarCeldaProducto(String codigo) {

       if(celda1.getProducto().getCodigo() == codigo){
            return celda1;
        }
        else if (celda2.getProducto().getCodigo() == codigo){
            return celda2;
        }
        else if(celda3.getProducto().getCodigo() == codigo){
            return celda3;
        }
        else if(celda4.getProducto().getCodigo() == codigo){
            return celda4;
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Cuando hice el debug, me sale que cuando invoco el método getProducto() todos me dan null, como si no hubiese ingresado valores

El método buscarCelda() me retorna la celda mediante el código celda:

```
public Celda buscarCelda(String codigo) {
    if (celda1.getCodigo() == codigo) {
        return celda1;
    }
    if (celda2.getCodigo() == codigo) {
        return celda2;
    }
    if (celda3.getCodigo() == codigo) {
        return celda3;
    }
    if (celda4.getCodigo() == codigo) {
        return celda4;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

mientras que el método buscarCelda Producto me retorna la celda pero basándose en el código del producto

Comment: Tienes dos métodos muy similares: `buscarCelda()` y `buscarCeldaProducto()`. Además, la comparación de cadenas deberías hacerla con [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals\(java.lang.Object\)) en lugar de `==`.

Comment: Ahí explique su diferencia, y en el código ya usé el equals, pero sigue sin funcionar, no me setea bien los valores, ese es el problema :(
pero no se cómo solucionarlo